# Why does pytz seem to not have any time zone information?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I just got pytz loaded. I can import it no problem. but when I call `pytz.all_timezones` I get an empty array (`[ ]`). I have used this package before and it list all the zones. What would be causing this to not list the time zones?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post example code. How are you calling pytz.all_timezones?

Comment: for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
 print(tz)

Comment: and pytz.all_timezones returns [ ]

Comment: Does anything get printed? Is your file called pytz.py? Does any other functionality of the module work such as pytz.common_timezones?

Comment: no it doesn't work either, but utc = pytz.utc and if I call UTC it returns <UTC> like in the docs

Comment: That's odd! How did you install it? I would try removing it and then reinstalling with pip or easy_install.

Comment: I used easy_install it said it was successful. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem like pretty odd behavior, but if you haven't already, I think the best course of action would be to try installing using setuptools, and more specifically running the command:

```
easy_install --upgrade pytz
```

If you havn't checked, this page contains some more information: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Another thing to try is see if the `all_timezones_set` set returns empty as well, and if not, see if you can use the set rather than `all_timezones`